# Access Multiple Email Boxes through Same user Account using Java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to read additional email boxes for a single user. For Example : if user A has two account. one its own and one more additionally configured for it. Is there a way in Java or Javamail API to access folders for both these accounts?

```
 store.connect("mail.abc.com","user","password");

  // Get a handle on the default folder
  folder = store.getFolder("inbox"); ///This works fine
 Folder[] f = store.getFolder("additionalbox").list(); // this doesnot work
 for(Folder fd : f){
     System.out.println(">>" +  fd.getName());
 }
```

Hierarchy is :

```
 user
     inbox

additionalbox
      inbox
```

Is there any way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a different Store object for each account and access them that way. Its up to your interface to make it look seamless to the user.